# Null result with Catch and Throw

Tags: warning-messages

I am trying to solve a physics problem of a man in a ferris wheel that needs to jump off at a certain angle to land in a boat that is moving at a constant velocity, however, whenever I compile my code, I get a "null" output. Is my code written incorrectly?

```
Clear[a, ω, R, H, h, Vb, θ, Pxo, Pyo, Vxo, Vyo, Ta, Tw, Ttotal, Bx, P, nterms]

a = 9.8; ω = .2; R = 30; H = 80; h = .01; Vb = 10;
θ[n_] := θ[n] = n*h;
Pxo[n_] := R*Sin[θ[n]];
Pyo[n_] := H + R*Cos[θ[n]];
Vxo[n_] := ω*R*Cos[θ[n]];
Vyo[n_] := -ω*R*Sin[θ[n]];
Ta[n_] := (Vyo[n] + Sqrt[Vyo[n]^2 + 2*a*Pyo[n]])/a;
Tw[n_] := θ[n]/ω;
Ttotal[n_] := Tw[n] + Ta[n];
Bx[n_] := Bx[n] = 150 - (Vb*Ttotal[n]);
P[n_] := P[n] = Vxo[n]*Ttotal + Pxo[n];
nterms = Catch[Do[If[(Bx[n] - P[n]) < 0, Throw[n]], {n, 1000}]];
Print[θ[nterms]]
```

Comment: Change to `Catch[Do[If[(Bx[n] - P[n]) < 0, Throw[n]], {n, 1000}]; "Not Thrown"]`, see what happens, I'm sure you can take it from there.

Comment: You are suggesting to add "Not Thrown" to the end of the command? Doing so still gave me the output ".01 Not Thrown"

Comment: That's the hint... nothing is getting thrown. If your intent is to return a value if none is thrown, replace the "not thrown" with something appropriate.

Comment: I want to throw the n value of when Bx[n] is equal to P[n]; that is why I have Throw [n]

Comment: And what if the condition is never True? BTW remove the memorization in the definitions of Bx and P as they make no sense here and will fill your memory with many incorrect definitions if any of the initial conditions or equations change. Also, do a ClearAll[Bx,P] before you continue. Additionally , it's better not to start user variable names with an uppercase character as this may conflict with built in names.

Answer (score 2):

I evaluated your code, but changed the last three lines to

```
P[n_] := P[n] = Vxo[n]*Ttotal[n]+ Pxo[n]; (* missing [n] added *)
nterms =
  Catch[
    Do[If[(Bx[n] - P[n]) < 0, Throw[n]], {n, 1000}];
    Throw[0]];
{nterms, θ[nterms]}
```

With these changes I got

> ```
> {419, 4.19}
> ```

Don't know if that is the numeric answer you are looking for, but I believe my changes reveals the bug in your code that has been troubling you.